# Updating Local Administrators

Tags: powershell, templates, puppet

**Purpose:**
Utilize Puppet to use an access control list to regulate which users should have local administrator accounts on a server. If a local admin is on a server that isn't on the ACL, that account is deleted.

**Setup:**
With Puppet, I'm using an EPP template and the PowerShell module to execute code to compare a formatted list of local administrators on the machine against an interpolated `$acl` variable containing the list of authorized users.

I have a hash containing usernames and initial passwords, e.g:

```
$credentials = { "test" => "t3st!!", "test2" => "t3st3r!" }
```

along with an array containing just the usernames, to be used as an access control list of users that should be authorized, e.g:

```
$acl = $credentials.keys
```

**`init.pp`:**

```
# Other code here, other functions work properly, variables import correctly

exec { "Removing unauthorized Local Administrators":
  command  => epp('usermgmt_test/remove-user.epp'),
  provider => powershell,
}
```

**`remove-user.epp`:**

```
function Get-LocalAdmin {
  # Get the list of local Administrators, format it, and convert to an array
  # for later iteration
  $list = net localgroup 'Administrators' | Select-Object -Skip 6
  $list = $list | Select-Object -First ($list.Count - 2)
  $list = $list.Trim()
  $list.Split("  ")
}

function Get-ACL {
  # Import the $acl variable from puppet, convert to string, format for
  # powershell, convert to array for later iteration
  $puppet = "<%= $acl %>"
  $puppet = $puppet.Trim('[',']')
  $puppet.Split(',')
}

$acl = Get-ACL
$adminList = Get-LocalAdmin

foreach ($user in $adminList) {
  if (($acl -notcontains $user) -and ($user -ne 'Administrator')) {
     net user $user /delete
  }
}
```

**Error:**
The manifest on the test server applies without errors, but does not actually delete any users and returns this confusing statement:

> $list.Split("  ")$puppet.Split(',')}Notice: /Stage[main]/Usermgmt_test/Exec[Removing unauthorized local Administrators]/returns: executed successfully

**Problem:**
I've checked that the `$acl` variable is interpolating properly into the EPP template and my test code in PowerShell works properly. I thought that it might be that Puppet was trying to interpolate the PowerShell variables, so I tried escaping those (`\$`) but that just threw a bunch of PowerShell errors. I'm kind of at a loss as to what I'm missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your post would be much more readable if you use code blocks for your Puppet code. Just highlight a block of code and click the `{}` button on the toolbar.

Comment: @PatrickLee Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Are you running PowerShell as Administrator?

Comment: Also, are you re-using the `$acl` variable? i.e. you have it once to get `$credentials.keys` and once as `$acl = Get-ACL` and then re-using it inside `Get-ACL` to fill the `$puppet` variable which is not used at all.

Comment: @HAL9256 
I assumed the powershell module for Puppet runs as admin, put in some code to throw an error if the prompt was not elevated, it ran fine. So yes it looks like I'm running as Admin.  As for the $acl variable, that's a good catch. I assumed that they would be separated by Puppet's interpolation. I changed the other $acl variable but the script still runs the same and produces the same output, so it seems like the variables were separated as I thought and not producing the error.

Comment: @HAL9256 Also to answer your other question, the <%= $acl %> shouldn't be empty, it contains an array equal to $credentials.keys that's being interpolated from the init.pp file. So in my example it would print out as [test,test2] (which is what I see when testing to verify that the variable has populated).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what the issue was. Turns out that Puppet templates get a little hinky when it comes to interpreting the white space. Once I took out all the white space the return values became something that made more sense.

I still had some issues to work out just with interpolating the array variable from puppet into the template (since Puppet only converts Strings) (Used Puppet's 'join' function from the stdlib module to turn the array into a string then did formatting in powershell to convert the string back to a usable array). But all good now!